# How to get the name of the current folder, not the dir to the folder

Tags: coldfusion

I know how to get the dir to the folder, but I'd like to get the name.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: but `dir`==`folder` isn't it?

Comment: YOu need to provide some more info here.  What are you trying to do, and what have you tried so far.  Post some code and explain what you want it to do and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A slightly more efficient method for doing what @Matt Shooks suggests would be to use list functions directly, rather than to convert to an array (since you only need to reference it once).

```
fullpath = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())
```

assuming that you are on Windows, and your fullpath looks something like c:\inetpub\site\dir, you can use this:

```
thisFolder = listlast(fullpath, "\/")
```

Remember that all list functions can take a delimiter (optionally) so you can treat any string delimited like this as a list, not just the default comma-delimited lists.

Comment: that only gets you the current file name as the template path includes the template itself. I thought the array looked a little cleaner then using ListGetAt to get the second to last element in the list.

Comment: I edited Ben's answer to also use getDirectoryFromPath() which strips the filename off the end of the string. I also added the slash as a parameter so that Unix-style directory strings wouldn't throw it off.

Comment: Thanks, @Al.  I usuallu use expandP{ath(), and forgot getCurrentTemplatePath() includes the fiilename.

Comment: Thank you Guys! Took it to the next level.

Answer (score 3):

If I read your question right, you are looking for just the current template folder name from the full path to the template.  Something like this should work:

```
<cfset path = ListToArray(GetCurrentTemplatePath(), "\") />
<cfset folderName = path[DecrementValue(ArrayLen(path))] />
<cfoutput>#folderName#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: +1 Thank you Matt, you steered this towards the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is finding the name of a file or folder inside of a directory, you can use:

```
<cfdirectory action="LIST" directory="C:\KnownDirectory" name="DirectoryContentsList" />
<ul>
<cfoutput query="DirectoryContentsList">
    <cfif DirectoryContentsList.TYPE eq "D">
        <li>#DirectoryContentsList.Name#</li>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
</ul>
```

This code should list all directories inside the specified directory.  I didn't test it, so there could be typos/errors, but it gives you the general idea.