# How can I get the parent of the current file?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

To get the current `*.cfm` file I use:

```
GetFileFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath())
```

Is there a simple way to get the parent of the current file?

I.e. if the current file is `...\MyApp\Users\addUser.cfm` I want to return `Users`.

Edit: the reason I want to do this is to check for access permission. Depending on path different policies will be enforced.

Edit: The linked question doesn't provide the correct answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the name of the current folder, not the dir to the folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833264/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-folder-not-the-dir-to-the-folder)

Comment: Yes it does @Roland just not the solution you've provided.

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate so as to make the existing solution in the SO community be made available to the viewers. Undoubtedly your answer below is a better one (+1) for it.

Comment: @Anurag you are right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
GetFileFromPath(GetFileInfo(GetCurrentTemplatePath()).parent)
```

This will return exactly what I need. Using the example from the question: just `Users` withouth the full path.

Comment: I was totally unaware of the existence of `.parent` in path functions